# Show error message with AJAX and Spring 3

Tags: ajax, spring, validation, response

I had a simple register form, and validation worked fine. Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String changeEmail(@Valid @ModelAttribute("editEmail") EditEmailForm editEmailForm, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "editAccount";
    }

    userService.changeEmail(editEmailForm);

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

and @Valid annotation did its job and if there were any errors on my form they were displayed in a correct position on my *.vm view.

But now I would like to use AJAX to send my form, so I changed my Controller to :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/email", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String changeEmail(@Valid @ModelAttribute("editEmail") EditEmailForm editEmailForm, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "ERROR";
    }

    userService.changeEmail(editEmailForm);

    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

Now I can display the ERROR message if validation fails, but how can I display the same messages as earlier? For example I write a wrong e-mail address, and I would like to see a message that there is a wrong e-mail address. Is it possible to achieve it ?

Thanks

Dawid

Answer (score 1):

You can return JSON String for your validation response. Let say you have `AjaxResponse` class

```
AjaxResponse{
    model; //form attribute
    status;  // OK or ERROR
    description; // message description such as error message
}
```

Comment: ok, that looks like a good solution, but could you write a simple example? I didn't use JSON earlier. how to populate JSON data and display errors on my view file?

Comment: I have code reference about Spring Rest with JSON. Hopefully you can modify according on you needs. https://github.com/bijukunjummen/mvc-samples

Tutorial from spring blog: http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Just do another check on the server side to check for a wrong email address.  If the email address is wrong then return something like "BAD_EMAIL", and handle it properly on the client side.

```
if (/* Email is bad */) {
    return "BAD_EMAIL";
}
```

On the client side, say you're using dojo,

```
dojo.xhrPost({
    url : "/email",
    ...various args
    load : function (response, ioArgs) {
        if (response === "BAD_EMAIL") {
            // show bad email message
        }
    }
});
```